# Why an OutOfMemoryError here if there is free heap space?

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

This question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682726/how-to-detect-the-cause-of-outofmemoryerror/11682810#comment15489544_11682810):

If I have a heap dump report that a `95%` of threads are left in `wait` or `parked` state, and that there is arround 750MB free heap memory available how is it possible to get an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`?
Since there seems to be free heap according to the report this seems weird to me!
Can anyone help me interpret this?

Comment: Show the whole error message...

Comment: @beny23:Everything is in the post I link to

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect the cause of OutofMemoryError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682726/how-to-detect-the-cause-of-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: @beny23:But it is not the same question.Why is it a duplicate?

Comment: you said that "everything is in the post that you linked to", so it would be easier to edit the original question.  In any case, I think that existing 695 threads is the likely reason it fails, because it just can't create any more.

Comment: @beny23:Why? Is `695` a huge number?

Comment: How many cores does your server have?  If you have too many threads then the processor would spend most of its time context switching, so more threads would probably cause a reduced throughput and there is a limit of how many threads an OS can handle. In any case 695 is definitely on the high side in my opinion.

Comment: @beny23:It is an 8-core machine. Java is 32 bit

Comment: So each core is expected to handle more than 80 threads... Also with 32-bit you've only got 2GB address space (Windows), so limited like this.  695 threads on 8 cores is definitely too much in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of OS are you using? Is it 32 Bit oder 64 Bit? Is your JDK 32 Bit oder 64 Bit? How much heap space do you need in total?
Try to run your program with more maximum heap space. I had the same problem while I wanted to transform a XML-file. You just to set following parameters:

In your shell:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar yourfile.jar
```

Comment: could you just accept the working answer? did anything work for you?

Answer (score 1):

OOME can be raised by Heap overflow or Stack overflow.
So if you can sure heap is enough, I recommend to check stack size.

Comment: I think you mean a lack of stack space, a stack overflow is caused by too many levels of recursion.

Comment: If the stack space is too small won't I get a `StackOverflow` error instead of an `OutofMemoryError`? http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/performance/jvm-tuning.xtp

Comment: As below link, OutOfMemoryError can be raised by stack size issue. https://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=605890